# How to get the confidence interval of each prediction on an ARIMA model

Tags: python, arima

I'm trying to get a "fuzzy" prediction of a timeseries, using an SARIMA model

My training set is `prices_train`, and the model is built as follows:

```
model_order = (0, 1, 1)
model_seasonal_order = (2, 1, 1, 24)
    
model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(
    prices_train, order=model_order, 
    seasonal_order=model_seasonal_order)
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
```

I know I can get a point forecast using this instruction:

```
pred = model_fit.forecast(3)
```

But I don't want a point forecast, I want a confidence interval of each predicted value so I can have a fuzzy timeseries of predicted values

I've seen tutorials such as [this one](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecast-uncertainty-using-confidence-intervals-python/), where they apply this code:

```
forecast, stderr, conf = model_fit.forecast(alpha=a)
```

However, it seems the library has been updated since 2017, because that does not work. I've read the `statsmodels` manual but I haven't found much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fit model should have a get_prediction() function that returns a prediction.
Then you can call `prediction.conf_int(alpha=a)`.

Comment: I've tried your answer, and it works, but I've found a more elegant way. However I'll mark it as accepted, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well I've found a way, I'll post it here in case anyone reading this in 2035 needs it:

Being `h` the number of predictions:

```
conf_ins = model_fit.get_forecast(h).summary_frame()
```

It returns a dataframe with the confidence interval of h predictions, indicating for each one:

- Average
- Mean squared error
- Minimum
- Maximum